# Floor equation $x=\frac{⌊x⌋}{x - ⌊x⌋}$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

> $$x=\frac{⌊x⌋}{x - ⌊x⌋}$$ for $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb N$.

I've tried putting $x = n + e$, where $n\in\mathbb Z, 0 < e < 1$ and I've got that $n + e = \frac{n}{e}$. Now, I don't know how should I approach problem further, and I am not sure if this is OK what I've done.

Comment: $n+e = \frac{n}{e}$ looks like a quadratic equation in $e$. Write that this equation has a root in $(0, 1)$

Comment: The use of the symbol $e$ here is, in my opinion, a bad choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your start is pretty good. Now continue by solving the quadratic equation:
$$n+e=\frac ne\iff ne+e^2=n^2\iff e=\frac{\pm\sqrt{n(n+4)}-n}2.$$

The assumption $e\geq0$ implies that $e=\frac{\sqrt{n(n+4)}-n}2$. Now, we [rationalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalisation_(mathematics)) to get

$$\frac{\sqrt{n(n+4)}-n}2=\frac{(\sqrt{n(n+4)}-n)(\sqrt{n(n+4)}+n)}{2(\sqrt{n(n+4)}+n)}=\frac{2n}{\sqrt{n(n+4)}+n}=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac 4n}}<1.$$

Hence, all solutions are of the form $x=n+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1+\frac 4n}}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Something to adjust in view of the discordance between `Simplify[Table[n + 2/(1 + Sqrt[1 + 4/n]), {n, 1, 6}]]` which produces $\left\{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right),\sqrt{3}+1,\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{21}+3\right),2 \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(3 \sqrt{5}+5\right),\sqrt{15}+3\right\}$ and `Reduce[Floor[x]/(x - Floor[x]) == x && x > 0 && x < 8, x, Reals]` which produces `x == 2 + 2 Sqrt[2] || x == 1 + Sqrt[3] || x == 1/2 (1 + Sqrt[5]) || 
 x == 1/2 (5 + 3 Sqrt[5]) || x == 3 + Sqrt[15] || 
 x == 1/2 (3 + Sqrt[21]) || x == 1/2 (7 + Sqrt[77])`

Comment: @user64494 Look closely at your own comment and you will see that both sets are exactly the same . There is no discordance .

Comment: You are right as `Simplify[Table[n + 2/(1 + Sqrt[1 + 4/n]), {n, 1, 7}]]` shows. That was my fault and  I am very sorry for that.

Comment: BTW, the biography of  Lyubomyr Zdomskyy ( https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=zdomsky%2C+l. ) is similar to yours.

Comment: @user64494 No biggie . And thanks for telling me about Lyubomyr Zdomskyy, I'll have a look at his CV.